# PHP XML parser few questions

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I've got XML that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250" ?> 
<offers>
<offer>
<offer_num>20790</offer_num>
<pics>
    <pic>http://old.mls.org.pl/pic!get.action?obrazId=11651</pic>
    <pic>http://old.mls.org.pl/pic!get.action?obrazId=16906</pic>
    <pic>http://old.mls.org.pl/pic!get.action?obrazId=9641</pic>
    <pic>http://old.mls.org.pl/pic!get.action?obrazId=9742</pic>
</pics>
</offer>
<offer>
<offer_num>20791</offer_num>
<pics>
    <pic>http://old.mls.org.pl/pic!get.action?obrazId=1432t</pic>
    <pic>http://old.mls.org.pl/pic!get.action?obrazId=12346906</pic>
</pics>
</offer>
</offers>
```

and my PHP parser:

```
foreach($xml->offer as $estate)
{
    $offer_signature = rtrim($estate->offer_num);
    $offer_photos = array();
    foreach($estate->pics as $photos)
    {
        $photo_url = $photos->pic;
        $photo_name = $offer_signature."_".md5($photo_url).".jpg";
        $offer_photos[] = $photo_name;
        downloadPhoto($photo_url, $photo_name);
    }
}
```

This parser works, I does parse the XML and downloadPhoto() function works... here's the code:

```
function downloadPhoto($photo_url, $photo_name)
{
    $dt = @file_get_contents($photo_url);
    if($dt)
    {
        $h = fopen(photo_path.$photo_name, 'w+');
        flock($h, 2);
        fwrite($h, $dt, strlen($dt));
        flock($h, 3);
        fclose($h);
    }
}
```

it downloads the picture, but only one picture PER offer so I assume something is wrong with parser code but I really don't know what.

I also wanted to change the line in parser:

```
$photo_name = $offer_signature."_".md5($photo_url).".jpg";
```

So $photo_name would be like **$offer_signature."_".[[picture number]].".jpg"**, for example **20790_01.jpg** but the problem is that I don't know how I could code it with foreach.

Comment: What does this photo_path represent??

Comment: DEFINE("photo_path", "/home/estate/pictures/");

Comment: As your pics element exists only once in the each offer element your loop running only one time. Try to change like this $estate->pics->pic. Hope this will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question #1

You need an additional loop:

```
foreach($xml->offer as $estate)
{
    $offer_signature = rtrim($estate->offer_num);
    $offer_photos = array();
    foreach($estate->pics as $photos)
    {

        foreach($photos as $pic){
            $photo_url = $pic;
            $photo_name = $offer_signature."_".md5($photo_url).".jpg";
            //$offer_photos[] = $photo_name;
            var_dump((string)$photo_url, (string)$photo_name);
        }
    }
}
```

## Question #2

Just create your own counter:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($xml->offer as $estate)
{
    foreach($estate->pics as $photos)
    {
        foreach($photos as $pic){
            var_dump(++$count, (string)$pic);
        }
    }
}
```